# Videos in WebView works only at first session

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an android application and screen with webview that contains a video in html like as:

```
String content = "...<script data-cfasync="false" defer type="text/javascript" src="https://..."></script>..."
```

and set this code for WebView:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

On first session when I try to watch video in WebView - everything OK. But if I restart my app (on second or next sessions) I only see screen of video, but it doesn't play and I cannot play it with button play on video. Why?

I try to disable or enable cache for webview, try to disable or enable dom storage - nothing help me. Also this problem doesn't happen on all devices, but on different android versions (for example, on Android 6, Android 8, but on some devices with this versions everything ok). Also if on problem devices I clear data of application in settings (clear all data, not clear cache) videos are working again.

Comment: Is your code inside `onCreate()` ? If yes, try to put it on `onStart()`.

Comment: @Maxouille Didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me:

`webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem happened on chrome version 73. So i have a trick to temporarily fix it, set this code for WebView:

```
     String tempUserAgent = webView
          .getSettings()
          .getUserAgentString()
          .substring(0, webView.getSettings()
                        .getUserAgentString()
                        .indexOf("AppleWebKit"));
     webView.getSettings()
          .setUserAgentString(tempUserAgent + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related to [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945287) in the 73.0.3683.90 release of Chrome. Updating to V74 of chrome should resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: I can't state exact nature of the cause. However, the problem seems to relate to the constraint that video playback in webview requires the user to initiate a gesture before the video can be played.   
In addition to not being able to play the video we observed the video could also not be opened in fullscreen. The error `API can only be initiated by a user gesture.` would be produced. Modifying the setting `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` to `false` would resolve the issue, however, this only serves as a workaround. On updating to V74 of Chrome/Webview, the issue has been resolved.